# Maven: Finding out if tests passed or failed after using maven.test.failure.ignore=true

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run a complete Maven build of multiple projects for an automated build tool. If unit tests fail, but the project itself builds correctly, I want to be able to continue the build and detect this after the build completes. I tried doing this:

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.reportsDirectory=/Users/bfraser/misc/reports
```

The "maven.test.failure.ignore" and "maven.test.error.ignore" properties work fine. However, surefire seems to ignore the "maven.test.reportsDirectory" completely (in fact, if you look at [the documentation for the test goal](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html), the `reportsDirectory` property is not documented to be tied to the system variable). This may be because I'm building a multi-module project? All reports seem to go in the target/ folder of the subprojects.

It is very difficult for me to be able to edit the POMs in an automated way since many of them have parent POMs that might be on a Nexus repo somewhere, etc. -- I need to be able to do this externally to the project (preferable via command line switches, but if I need to create some files so be it... as long as I don't have to edit the project POM it's all good).

I just need to know if any test failed. I'm not particularly fussy about what/how many tests failed.

Comment: Can't you just use `-fae` to fail the build at the end, instead of playing with Surefire config?

Comment: @Tunaki - Sure, but I need to find out if the failure was due to a unit test failure or a genuine build failure. If it's just a unit test failure, I can go on and build several other projects possibly then try to run some higher-level integration tests on remote machines, etc.